# Генерация соли в C#

Tags: c#, криптография

Хочу использовать RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class для генерации случайной соли, но дело в том. что мне нужны не только числа, но и символы. Вопрос, как сгенерировать соль, которая будет состоять не только из чисел?

Comment: Использовать число как индекс для массива с буквами/символами/чем угодно?

Comment: В компьютере всё есть число. Зачем вам символ? Почему соль — не просто набор байт?

Comment: И да, вы случайно не путаете байты и их строковое представление?

Comment: @VladD , не совсем понял ваш вопрос "почему соль не просто набор байт".

Comment: @IWProgrammer: Ну, в криптографии соль — практически всегда набор байт, я не помню случая, чтобы она была _строкой_. В связи с этим есть подозрение, что ошибочной является сама постановка задачи.

Comment: @VladD дело в том, что я буду складывать соль с паролем и заносить в БД. Каким образом я занесу соль в БД, если это просто набор байтов?

Comment: @IWProgrammer: А каким образом вы заносите зашифрованное сообщение? Оно совершенно точно набор байтов.

Comment: @IWProgrammer тип поля BLOB или применение base64 спасут отца русской демократии

Comment: @VladD , можете привести небольшой пример? Я не совсем понимаю, каким образом набор байтов запишется в БД.

Comment: @IWProgrammer: Ну каким образом вы пишете туда зашифрованное сообщение? Или вы его туда вовсе не пишете? И да, почему пароль — это строка?

Comment: @VladD , ну пользователь вводит пароль, он шифруется SHA256, далее генерируется соль, шифруется  SHA256 и складывается с паролем. Это всё записывается в БД. Да. пока что я туда ничего не пишу, ибо столкнулся с проблемой непонимания генерации соли

Comment: @IWProgrammer обычно складывается соль с паролем, шифруется и в зашифрованном виде заносится в базу, поэтому вы упустили действие шифрования. Но суть не в этом, в программе символ представлен числом и байтами, поэтому их можно свободно между друг другом преобразовывать. Для примера только вопрос, чем шифровать будете?

Comment: @AlexKrass , SHA256

Comment: @IWProgrammer: Ну вот подумайте. Допустим, проблему с солью вы решили — как вы будете записывать зашифрованный текст в базу? Это набор байт, а никакая не строка. В любом случае вам придётся писать в базу байты, а не строки. Криптография работает с байтами и только с ними.

Comment: @VladD , BitConverter.ToString()?

Comment: @IWProgrammer, лучше уж в БД иметь `BLOB`-поле

Comment: @IWProgrammer: Вот так прямо с соединяющими дефисами? https://ideone.com/8IyYaq Ну допустим. Вот так же и пишите соль, полученную как набор байт.